# The meaning of "write your story on a treadmill desk"

Tags: meaning

The passage below comes from a [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-39292389).

> Prof Gurven said: "I would say we need a more holistic approach to physical exercise rather than just at the weekend. Bicycle to work, take the stairs, write your story on a treadmill desk." (I didn't)

I'd like to ask the meaning of the phrase *write your story on a treadmill desk*.

I don't understand what *write your story* implies.

Is it just about *writing any story while exercising* or does it imply any specific writing, like, *taking the record of exercise*?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Google `treadmill desk`: https://www.nordictrack.com/cmsstatic/product/NTL99115_xxl-97842.png

Comment: Literary analysis (what does this passage mean?) is generally off topic. Exceptions can be made when there is a clearly identified source of concern about an element of the English language that would be interesting and useful to many future visitors. That does not appear to be the situation here.

Comment: @MetaEd - It's not clear that "literary analysis" is required here.  It's more a matter of simple definitions.

Comment: @HotLicks there is no question of definitions here. The question asks whether to interpret the text as "writing a story (while) on a treadmill desk", or "writing a story on (the subject of) a treadmill desk".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, *write your story* is just synonymous for *do your daily job*, whether it involves writing an actual story (e.g. if you're a journalist), answering the telephone or some other activity typical for an office job.

Answer (score 2):

"Holistic", in the above quote, is apparently being used above to mean "integrated".  The overall gist of the quote is that exercise should be integrated into ones lifestyle, rather than being restricted to just a few hours in the gym on weekends.

Bicycling to work and taking the stairs at work and in your apartment building, vs using the elevator, are ways to do this.  Another way is to use a [treadmill desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treadmill_desk), so that you can exercise while you work at what would normally be considered a "desk job" (such as "writing a story").

[image]